# How to prevent Capistrano from displaying password when deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I recently started deploying my rails apps using Capistrano, but I can't seem to figure out how to not display my password when deploying the app when it prompts me for my password.

I get the following warning,

`Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.`

I installed both of those gems, and my password is still being echoed in clear text.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in config/deploy/production.rb

```
set :ssh_options, {
  keys: %w(/Users/artemadamcov/.ssh/id_rsa),
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
  port: 4321
}
```

And enter it in terminal

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I didn't need to specify the port because it was already specified in the `production.rb`

Comment: Just `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` saved me. I should've tried your solution earlier...