# How do I suppress password from displaying in the clear with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, capistrano

How do I suppress my password from being displayed in the clear when using Capistrano?  I’m using Rails 4.2.7 on Mac El Capitan.  The message said to install the Highline gem, which I did, but that doesn’t suppress the password from appearing …

```
localhost:myproject davea$ sudo gem install highline
Successfully installed highline-1.7.8
Parsing documentation for highline-1.7.8
Done installing documentation for highline after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
localhost:myproject davea$ cap production deploy:initial
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
myser@12.12.12.12’s password:asdf
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add the highline gem to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'highline'
end
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in config/deploy/production.rb

```
set :ssh_options, {
keys: %w(/Users/artemadamcov/.ssh/id_rsa),
forward_agent: true,
auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
port: 4321
}
```

[How to prevent Capistrano from displaying password when deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665180/how-to-prevent-capistrano-from-displaying-password-when-deploying)